# Using multiple map_async (Multiprocessing) in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, performance, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have sample code that uses map_async in Multiprocessing using Python 3. What I'm trying to figure out is how I can run map_async(a, c) and map_async(b, d) concurrently. But it seems like to second map_async(b, d) statement seems to run when the first one is about to finish. Is there a way I can run two map_async functions to run at the same time? I tried to search online but didn't get the answer that I wanted. Below is the sample code. If you have other suggestions, I'm very happy to listen to that as well. Thank you all for the help!

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time
import os

def a(i):
  print('First': i)
  return

def b(i):
  print('Second': i)
  return

if __name__ = '__main__':
  c = range(100)
  d = range(100)

  pool = Pool(os.cpu_count())
  pool.map_async(a, c)
  pool.map_async(b, d)

  pool.close()
  pool.join()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`map_async` simply splits the iterable in a set of chunks and sends those chunks via a `os.pipe` to the workers. Therefore, two subsequent calls to `map_async` will appear to the workers as a single list composed by the join of the two above mentioned sets.

This is the correct behaviour as the workers really don't care about which `map_async` call a chunk belongs. Running two `map_async` in parallel would not bring any improvement in terms of speed or throughput.

If for any reason you really need the two call to be executed in parallel, the only way is to create two different `Pool` objects. I would nevertheless recommend against such approach as it would make things much more unpredictable.

Comment: No, all `Pool` implementations behave the same. It's a design principle. You split an iterable in chunks and work concurrently on the chunks.